# Presenting a paper on a video

Tags: copyright, presentation

I want to know about copyrights for presenting a paper on a public video.

For example, can I explain and show text and pictures of last month's good papers on a specific topic in a video on Youtube? Does this violate the copyright?

In the caption and video, I will mention the paper's Journal/Conf and authors, but I want to make sure if this is okay to do. Or should I ask directly from each journal?

Thanks.

Comment: How big is the audience, or do you intend to publish the video, say on the internet?

Comment: On the internet,e.g. on a youtube channel.

Comment: Which jurisdiction? If you're interested in North American law, there is a probable duplicate question [Is it "fair use" to use figures from a publication in monetized educational material?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/95605/17254). A similar question on Law.SE discusses the case of European laws: [CanI (sic) use the figures in research papers or books for YouTube videos under fair use?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/49512/27339)

Comment: Note that the world of YouTube has started to operate under rules that are somewhat replacing our legal framework... Here's a fantastic video about the greater picture that is very relevant to your question. https://youtu.be/1Jwo5qc78QU

Comment: Also, you will get better answers on the law stack exchange than here. I suggest transferring your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are proposing to republish material that is almost certainly under copyright. For that you need to be careful. The easiest way is to ask the publishers who are the most likely copyright holders.

If you are one of the authors of a paper you probably have license for some, but not all things.

But, you are limited by fair use. Just as you can't quote too extensively from a publication in another, even with citation, you can't put too much of the text in a public facing video.

Images are even more of a problem. While they may not take up a lot of room in a printed publication, they can convey a lot of information, similar to quoting a lot of text. You might need specific permission for each image.

The problem is that "fair use" is a judgement call and the copyright owners might object. One of the considerations of fair use is whether the new work diminishes the (economic) value of the original. A video might well do that. Ask the publisher to be safe.

---

Caveat: copyright law is a local issue. It varies a lot from place to place. What might be allowed in one place might not in another. But the internet is "world facing" generally.